# No disk space after switching from B+ to 2 model B

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, hard-drive, storage

Before switching to the RPi 2 model B, I used the commands `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. However, on using the new RPi 2 model B, it keeps saying no disk space left on device. I am using an 8GB SD card with Raspbian. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Edit in the output from `df /`.

Comment: After searching through the filesystem more thoroughly, it appears the disk space issue may have been unrelated to the ugprade. My log files were taking up a lot of space, as well as a few other things.

Comment: That's a lot of logs to fill 8 GB.  If it has to do with the `journald` directory let me know, that thing can be horrendous and you should reconfigure it.  I can't tell you off the top of my head how but I could take a look later on.

Comment: You might wish to write up your comment up as an Answer (which/what log was a particular problem?) and "Accept" it - unless @goldilocks comes up with a better or more useful answer. Answering questions and accepting one for this Question will improve your *reputation* and open up more functionality on the Stack Exchange site for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to have a look on the partition of your SD card.

You can do it from the Raspberry but the SD card should not be mounted or used for boot or OS to run.

Use a computer with Ubuntu distro with `gparted`, it's easier and quicker. Run

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

if you don't already have it.

Open `gparted`, select your SD (look at the top right).

You will see that you've free space and you can resize this partition. That works perfectly for me.

So in `gparted` select, unmount, resize and apply changes, and exit.
That works for me... twice!